# Inline round images with right text in two lines

Tags: html, css, css-position

In the fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/7xd06gum/ I'm trying to show three images with the text under two lines on the right but I'm struggling to do that. Do you have any suggestions? Basically the image need to be on the left and the text on the right with the name on top line and the job on the new line. Do you have any suggestions?

**HTML**

```
<ul class="upcoming-people__nav">
  <li class="upcoming-people__navItem">
    <img class="upcoming-people__img" src="https://media4.popsugar-assets.com/files/2015/01/28/952/n/1922398/3f506df2_main.jpg" />
    <span class="upcoming-people__name">James Cook</span>
    <span class="upcoming-people__job">Manager, AAX spa</span>
  </li>
  <li class="upcoming-people__navItem">
    <img class="upcoming-people__img" src="https://media4.popsugar-assets.com/files/2015/01/28/952/n/1922398/3f506df2_main.jpg" />
    <span class="upcoming-people__name">James Cook</span>
    <span class="upcoming-people__job">Manager, AAX spa</span>
  </li>
  <li class="upcoming-people__navItem">
    <img class="upcoming-people__img" src="https://media4.popsugar-assets.com/files/2015/01/28/952/n/1922398/3f506df2_main.jpg" />
    <span class="upcoming-people__name">James Cook</span>
    <span class="upcoming-people__job">Manager, AAX spa</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.upcoming-people__nav {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.upcoming-people__navItem {
  display: inline;
  color: #000000;
  padding-right: 100px;
}
.upcoming-people__img {
  width: 70px;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.upcoming-people__name {
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 0.015em;
}
.upcoming-people__job {
  margin-left: 10px;
  color: #000000
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may wrap text in a p ans set both, img and p inline-block. Vertical-align is then possible too.
white-space:nowrap on li to make sure img and p stay side by side : https://jsfiddle.net/7xd06gum/6/

```css
.upcoming-people__nav {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.upcoming-people__navItem {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #000000;
  padding-right: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.upcoming-people__img {
  width: 70px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.upcoming-people__navItem p {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.upcoming-people__name {
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 0.015em;
  display: block;
}

.upcoming-people__job {
  margin-left: 10px;
  color: #000000
}
```

```html
<ul class="upcoming-people__nav">
  <li class="upcoming-people__navItem">
    <img class="upcoming-people__img" src="https://media4.popsugar-assets.com/files/2015/01/28/952/n/1922398/3f506df2_main.jpg" />
    <p><span class="upcoming-people__name">James Cook</span>
      <span class="upcoming-people__job">Manager, AAX spa</span>

    </p>
  </li>
  <li class="upcoming-people__navItem">
    <img class="upcoming-people__img" src="https://media4.popsugar-assets.com/files/2015/01/28/952/n/1922398/3f506df2_main.jpg" />

    <p><span class="upcoming-people__name">James Cook</span>
      <span class="upcoming-people__job">Manager, AAX spa</span>

    </p>
  </li>
  <li class="upcoming-people__navItem">
    <img class="upcoming-people__img" src="https://media4.popsugar-assets.com/files/2015/01/28/952/n/1922398/3f506df2_main.jpg" />
    <p>
      <span class="upcoming-people__name">James Cook</span>
      <span class="upcoming-people__job">Manager, AAX spa</span>

    </p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7xd06gum/6/

Answer (score -1):

1. Add to image `float: left`
2. Wrap your text into the `div`
3. Change `span` with text into block element.

https://jsfiddle.net/7xd06gum/5/